# ARIMAX equation for order (2,1,1)

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to arimax. Can any one help me out for arriving at the equation for arimax of order (2,1,1)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's arimax? Can you be more specific in the question please

Comment: Are you using PyFlux? Are you asking for some sample code? Or some maths derivation?

Comment: Please post what you've tried up to now. If you haven't tried, maybe you need a tutorial of arimax. Is this helpful? (https://barnesanalytics.com/analyzing-multivariate-time-series-using-arimax-in-python-with-statsmodels)

Comment: Well, I am using SARIMAX from statsmodel. I am looking forward to a mathematical equation with the AR and MA terms

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
import pyflux as pf

model = pf.ARIMAX(data = your_data, formula='MEG~CrudeOil+1', ar=2, ma=1, integ = 1,family=pf.Normal())
```